# How to put middleware in it's own file in Node.js / Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am new to the whole Node.js thing, so I am still trying to get the hang of how things "connect".

I am trying to use the [express-form](http://dandean.github.com/express-form/docs/) validation. As per the docs you can do

```
app.post( '/user', // Route  
  form( // Form filter and validation middleware
    filter("username").trim()
  ),

  // Express request-handler gets filtered and validated data
  function(req, res){
    if (!req.form.isValid) {
      // Handle errors
      console.log(req.form.errors);

    } else {
      // Or, use filtered form data from the form object:
      console.log("Username:", req.form.username);

    }
  }
);
```

In App.js. However if I put something like `app.get('/user', user.index);` I can put the controller code in a separate file. I would like to do the same with the validation middleware (or put the validation code in the controller) to make the App.js file easier to overview once I start adding more pages.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Basically I would like to put something like `app.get('/user', validation.user, user.index);`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This is how you define your routes:

**routes.js:**

```
module.exports = function(app){
    app.get("route1", function(req,res){...})
    app.get("route2", function(req,res){...})
}
```

This is how you define your middlewares:

**middlewares.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    formHandler: function(req, res, next){...}
}
```

**app.js:**

```
// Add your middlewares:
middlewares = require("middlewares");
app.use(middlewares.formHandler);
app.use(middlewares...);

// Initialize your routes:
require("routes")(app)
```

Another way would be to use your middleware **per route**:

**routes.js:**

```
middlewares = require("middlewares")
module.exports = function(app){
    app.get("route1", middlewares.formHandler, function(req,res){...})
    app.get("route2", function(req,res){...})
}
```

I hope I answer your questions.

Comment: It was the per-route approach I was after. Thanks for the extensive explanation

Comment: in this example, is there a one-liner to apply all middlewares.js in app.js?

Comment: Only answer/explanation on the topic that made sense to me after a couple days struggling with the issue when learning node.js. Amazing.

Answer (score 3):

You can put middleware functions into a separate module in the exact same way as you do for controller functions.  It's just an exported function with the appropriate set of parameters.

So if you had a `validation.js` file, you could add your `user` validation method as:

```
exports.user = function (req, res, next) {
  ... // validate req and call next when done
};
```

Comment: yeah "appropriate set of parameters" is the trick :) I haven't fully grasped the export/require relationship yet