# How do I set middlewares on express in other file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, node-modules

I have this express configuration in the server.js:

```
  const app = express();
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(crossOriginRequest());
  app.use(setSecurityHttpHeaders());
  app.use(preventMongoOperatorInjection());
  app.use(preventXssAttacks());
  app.listen(80);
```

How can I set all this middlewares in another file? Example:

```
  const app = express();
  setBasicMiddlewares(app);
  app.listen(80);
```

And in setBasicMiddlewares.js (this is an example of what I want, I don't belive it works):

```
function setBasicMiddlewares(app) {
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(crossOriginRequest());
  app.use(setSecurityHttpHeaders());
  app.use(preventMongoOperatorInjection());
  app.use(preventXssAttacks());
}

export default setBasicMiddlewares;
```

I'm using node modules with "import" and "export default"

This question is not similar to another question because of the ES6 modules. And the other question is asking about the routes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put middleware in it's own file in Node.js / Express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958296/how-to-put-middleware-in-its-own-file-in-node-js-express-js)

Comment: Consider your use of `export default` -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40294870/module-exports-vs-export-default-in-node-js-and-es6

Comment: Hi daddygames! I read the question that you send, but my enviroment uses node v14.8, so it does read ES6. I'm wrong to asume that I should use 'export default' (maybe I didn't understand something)? The question that you send it was write 4 years ago.

Comment: FaltFe, this doesn't answer my question because it is not write in ES6, and it does refers to a diferent type of middleware

Comment: app.listen twice is simply not going to work, you should have one entrypoint (index.js, server.js etc), then import/require **routes** which use their own packages etc if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the creation of your `express()` instance in another file/module and export it.

**app.js**

```
// import dependencies of course

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(crossOriginRequest());
app.use(setSecurityHttpHeaders());
app.use(preventMongoOperatorInjection());
app.use(preventXssAttacks());

module.exports = app;
```

Then, in your server.js, import your `app` and setup your server.

**server.js**

```
var app = require('../app');
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(process.env.PORT || '3000');
```

This is also the default app structure you get from using [express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) which I would strongly recommend for you.